# Boot from USB Connected SSD

Tags: usb, boot, pi-3b+, boot-issues, root

It seems that existing guides of how to boot from USB are out of date, and the one here (https://learn.adafruit.com/external-drive-as-raspberry-pi-root/hooking-up-the-drive-and-copying-slash) didn't work, as it didn't alter the root, though it copied all my files to the SDD.

I don't want to mess up any important files, as I don't know much about them. Is there any up-to-date tutorial for a beginner?

Comment: What Raspbery Pi model you are using? Is it a RPi 3B+?

Comment: `It seems that existing guides of how to boot from USB are out of date` no, they are not, of course, depends on what you're reading. Going to AdaFruit to get instructions on raspberry pi is like going to a driving instructor to learn how to fly a jumbo jet. With respect to AdaFruit, they barely know their own "products" so, you're not going to get any useful information about something they didn't "make"

Comment: @Ingo, yes, it is a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, from the box. Do you know of and recommend a guide that works without any in-depth technical knowledge?

Comment: Hmm. I found a topic here (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1385780) and the third post seems to fit my needs. I'll update this if it works.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Raspbberry Pi 3B+ has improved boot capabilities. It can boot from any USB drive out of the box. Just flash an [Raspbian Image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) to the USB storage like you do it with a SD Card. Put it into one USB port on the RasPi and boot. The only thing is that there must not be a SD Card in its slot. The RasPi will always first boot from it if it find one.

Comment: Except that it's not **any USB drive**, just some USB drives.